# white Elephant build issue

Tags: ant

I'm trying to do a POC using white elephant-LinkedIn product in our hadoop CDH4.5 test environment.
I have used my local-pc to build WAR file after downloading the code(Zip file) from  GitHub but encountered with below error message.Looks like issue with ANT libs.please provide some blogposts or wiki doc for installing the sane any pointers are really appreciated.
Reference:
    https://engineering.linkedin.com/hadoop/white-elephant-hadoop-tool-you-never-knew-you-needed

C:\Arun\white-elephant-master\server\build.xml:41: Execute failed: java.io.IOExc
    eption: Cannot run program ".\setup.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a va
    lid Win32 application
            at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
            at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
    a13CommandLauncher.java:58)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
    a:106)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
    cutor.java:41)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
            at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
    Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32
     application
            at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)

```
-Arun
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation for white elephant isn't telling you specifically, it's pretty clear from a quick glance at the error you're getting and the code you've linked to that this is a *nix only application.

Your build is telling you "Execute failed: java.io.IOExc eption: Cannot run program ".\setup.sh": CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a va lid Win32 application at...".  This means that Windows is trying to treat the file "setup.sh" as an executable.  .sh files are shell scripts meant to be run on Linux, Unix, and maybe MacOS X systems.